python was not found, run without arguments to install from the microsoft store, or disable this shortcut from settings
I got this problem, from Visual Studio Code: python was not found, run without arguments to install from the microsoft store, or disable this shortcut from settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
I was trying to configure Code runner, i added this in the settings : "clear && python3 -u".
I installed python 3.12.4
any help please.

Open your search bar if you are on windows and search Python. Once you've located Python, click the option "Open file Location". Once you've clicked it, you'll see the highlighted python version. Right click and click on the option "Open File Location". If you do that you'll be directly taken to the Python folder where you have installed python on your system
Copy that top part "Ctrl +c" . After that, go back to the search bar of your windows and type ' environment ' ,by just typing that you'll see a file come up called "Edit the system environment variables" just click on ' Open'.
On the system properties dialog box click on the environment variables option and in the systems variables you'll see an option called as "Path". Click on Path and click on 'Edit' then click on 'New' and paste the path you copied "CTRL + V". After that go back to the Python folder again where you'll see you have a folder named as "Scripts" double click it, copy the same exact path like we did above and go to environment variables > to system variables > Path > Edit > New > Paste it . Click on OK everywhere. Go back to the terminal on VS Code or Command Prompt and type
;    python --version  by typing that you should be able to see the python version.
